# How do I convert the limit definition of differentiability to different variables?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to convert this:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - J(h)}{\|h\|} = 0$$

Into the version of the limit where it has $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ instead of $h$. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h=(x,y)$, so...
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x_{0}+x,y_{0}+y)-f(x_{0},y_{0})-J(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=0$$

Note that $J$ is the derivative (a linear operator) at $(x_{0},y_{0})$, and $J(x,y)$ is $J$ operating on the vector $h=(x,y)$; this is why we don't use this expanded coordinate notation since it makes things look ugly and confusing.

Comment: Thanks, how do you know $h = (x,y)$? This probably requires literature but I'm not quite sure what to enter as a search query into Google (which is why I asked this question on here).

Comment: Because $h$ is just a displacement vector (from the point in question, $(x_{0},y_{0})$), and you send it to $0$. Being a vector, it has coordinates. Call them $(x,y)$, or anything you wish.